# Django Login using user class redirecting to the same page

Tags: html, django, authentication

I am new to Django and I am developing a website that has some functions like Login and Register. I have already tried the register function (`registrarUsuario`) and I think it is working properly but when I try to Log In using the account created it redirects me to the same page and the user does not Log In (I checked this with `request.user.is_authenticated`). I have researched a lot and I haven't found a solution yet.

**Note**: the login used to work with predefined users that I created with django (just username and password)... but I am using my own model WITH THE `User` Class

I will post the register User code just in case the problem is there.

**VIEWS**

```
def registroUsuarios(request): #REGISTER USER FUNCTION

    form=RegistrarUsuario(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        data=form.cleaned_data
        regDB=User.objects.create_user(data.get("username"),data.get("password"))
        usuario=Usuario(user=regDB,correo=data.get("correo"),nombreCompleto=data.get("nombreCompleto"),direccionUsuario=data.get("direccionUsuario"),perfil=data.get("perfil"))
        regDB.save() 
        usuario.save()
    usuarios=Usuario.objects.all()
    form=RegistrarUsuario()
    titulo="Mis Perris | Registro Usuarios"
    return render(request,"registroUsuarios.html",{'titulo':titulo,'form':form,'usuarios':usuarios})

def ingresar(request):     #LOG IN FUNCTION 
    titulo="Mis Perris | Login"
    form=Login(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        data=form.cleaned_data
        user=authenticate(username=data.get("username"),password=data.get("password"))
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            return redirect('inicio')
    return render(request,"login.html",{'form':form,'titulo':titulo})
```

**MODELS**

```
class Usuario(models.Model):  #USER CLASS
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #username=models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=20)
    #password=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    correo=models.EmailField(max_length=30)
    nombreCompleto=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    direccionUsuario=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    perfil=models.CharField(max_length=20,default="Guest")
```

**FORMS**

```
perfiles=(
    ('Administrador','Administrador'),
    ('Guest','Guest'),
    ('Usuario','Usuario'),
)



class RegistrarUsuario(forms.Form): #REGISTER USER
    username=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(),label="Nombre de Usuario")
    password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(),label="Contraseña")
    correo=forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(),label="Correo")
    nombreCompleto=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(),label="Nombre Completo")
    direccionUsuario=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(),label="Dirección")
    perfil=forms.ChoiceField(choices=perfiles)

class Login(forms.Form):
    username=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(),label="Nombre de Usuario")
    password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(),label="Contraseña")
```

**LOGIN.HTML**

```
{% extends "master.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block Login %}
<section class="login-block">
    <div class="logincontainer">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 register-sec">
        <h2 class="text-center">Iniciar Sesión</h2>
        <form method="POST" class="login-form">


            <div class="col-10">
                {% csrf_token %} 
                {{form.as_p}} 
            </div>


<div class="form-check col-md-11">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-login float-left">Iniciar Sesión</button>
<input class="btn btn-login float-right" type="button" value="Registrarse" onclick="location.href = '{% url 'registro' %}';"></button>
</div>

</form>
<div class="copy-text"><a href="#">¿Olvidaste tu Contraseña? Clic AQUÍ</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</section>

{% endblock %}
```

**REGISTROUSUARIOS.HTML**  (Register user)

```
{% extends "master.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block RegistroUsuarios %}

<section class="register-block">
    <div class="registercontainer">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 register-sec">
        <h2 class="text-center">Registro Usuarios</h2>
        <form method="POST" class="register-form">


<div class="col-6">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_p}}
</div>

<div class="form-check col-md-6">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-register float-right">Registrarse</button>
</div>

</form>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

P.S: Sorry if the code is in spanish

EDIT: I have already tried deleting the DB and migrations files and doing `makemigrations` and `migrate` again

EDIT 2: I listed all the users I have registered and they are being registered correctly so it seems that the problem is in the login. I also created a `superuser` using django commands and it works! But I still can not find the error

Comment: In the class Usuario, have you migrated with username and password or the #tag is present before just to add it as reference?

Comment: What is the value of `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your `settings.py`? @Runsis

Comment: @Satevg I don't have any attribute called `AUTH_USER_MODEL` but that probably isn't a problem. I even checked everything with my professor and he could not find the error..

Comment: @BidhanMajhi It is just commented, I have not migrated using that